# sphinx: internal short reference to python class

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

How can I achieve something like this in sphinx?

```
Creates a `ClassName`_ instance.

.. _ClassName: :class:`~very.long.path.to.ClassName`
```

I would like to have short links to long class/methods/etc references in order to make my documentation more readable.

Comment: It looks like what you have should work. The tilde (`~`) makes it so that only the last part of the target is used as the link text.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found so far to reduce the length of my python references is to use the current module directive:

```
.. py:currentmodule:: very.long.path.to.package

This is my :class:`~module_in_package.ClassName`.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I finally got things to work using reST [Substitutions](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#substitutions). Try this:

```
Creates a |ClassName| instance.

.. |ClassName| replace:: :class:`~very.long.path.to.ClassName`
```

Comment: Will give it a try and comment back later!